# Schubert class in the Grassmannian G(3,6)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

How to compute the Schubert class $\sigma$$^2$$_2$$_1$ in the Grassmannian G(3,6)?

I remember the result is $\sigma$$_3$$_3$ + 2$\sigma$$_3$$_2$$_1$ + $\sigma$$_2$$_2$$_2$.

Comment: In maple `with(schubert)` `grass(3, 6, c)` `Gc[relations_]` yields the ideal I use in M2 below. `sigma33 := schur([3, 3], Qc)` `sigma321 := schur([3, 2, 1], Qc)` `sigma222 := schur([2, 2, 2], Qc)` `sigma33+2*sigma321+sigma222` yields `c2^3`. `sigma21 := schur([2, 1], Qc)` and `sigma21^2` yields `(c1*c2-c3)^2`. Now in M2 `R=ZZ[c_1,c_2,c_3,Degrees=>{1,2,3}]` `I=ideal(2*c_1*c_3+c_2^2-3*c_2*c_1^2+c_1^4, 2*c_3*c_2-3*c_3*c_1^2-3*c_1*c_2^2+4*c_2*c_1^3-c_1^5, c_3^2-6*c_3*c_1*c_2+4*c_3*c_1^3-c_2^3+6*c_2^2*c_1^2-5*c_2*c_1^4+c_1^6)` `(c_2^3-(c_1*c_2-c_3)^2)%I` yields `0`: at least your memory checks out.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to work by hand, if it is not too complicated.

Comment: These [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-727-topics-in-algebraic-geometry-intersection-theory-on-moduli-spaces-spring-2006/lecture-notes/week1.pdf) perform this calculation (see figure 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sigma_{2,1} = \sigma_2\cdot\sigma_1 - \sigma_3$, hence
$$
\sigma_{2,1}^2 = \sigma_{2,1}\cdot\sigma_2\cdot\sigma_1 - \sigma_{2,1}\cdot\sigma_3.
$$
By Pieri rule
$$
\sigma_{2,1}\cdot\sigma_2\cdot\sigma_1 = (\sigma_{3,2} + \sigma_{3,1,1} + \sigma_{2,2,1})\cdot\sigma_1 = \sigma_{3,3} + 3\sigma_{3,2,1}+\sigma_{2,2,2},
$$
while 
$$
\sigma_{2,1}\cdot\sigma_3 = \sigma_{3,2,1}.
$$
Subtracting, you get the result.

Alternatively, one can directly use the Littlewood-Richardson rule.